# Sql Developer export Table to .xls (.xml)

Tags: excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I guys,

I'm trying to export a table to Excel with `SqlDeveloper` but I don't manage to do it.

I have selected the table -> right click -> and try to export it in Excel format but, when try to open it with **MS Excel** I obtain an error.

If I export it to `.xml` format and try to open it with **MS Excel** this is the result:

[image]

The format is completely wrong! I want all the column in the header (in the top of the sheet) and the column value below, row by row.

Is there a way to transform this output??

Thank you all

Comment: there are 4 options, CSV, Excel (XLS), Excel (XLSX) and Excel (XML) - have you tried all of those?

Comment: also, what's the error? and can you share the table/sql so we can try what you're trying?

Comment: when you export with excel compatible options,header will come in excel while exporting.

Comment: Thank you all for your support. The query is very simple, it's just a `select * from table;` -> the result appear on `SQL Developer` window -> select all -> export. With my version of `SQL Developer` I haven't `Excel(XLS)`, `Excel(XLSX)` I have just `excel.xml` and `.xml`. If I use the `excel.xml` format `Office 2010` doesn't open the file.  If I use the `.xml` format the file will open in the wrong format I have posted before. Thank you